# connecting sensirion SLF3S-4000B flow sensors to arduino uno r3 via I2C bus

Tags: arduino, digital-logic, sensor, i2c

I bought the following sensors for my project: https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/3730435.pdf

I am using two and they operate on 3.3V logic. They use a standard 6 pin picoblade 150mm connection. I am just unsure how to connect two sensors measuring separate flows using the SDA and SCL connections as arduino uno uses 5V logic. I have come across some using a TCA9548A module but am unsure of what value pull-up resistors to use and if I can connect both sensors in parallel to the SDA/SCL pins.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the sensors have identical I2C address, and no way to change it, or a select pin to allow only one of them to communicate at a time, they cannot be on the same bus. However, the manufacturer has an application note how to change the I2C address, so you should read it and decide yourself if that is something you want or can implement or if it is easier to keep these sensors on two separate buses.

The correct size pull-ups is a popular question. It depends on what want to do really and how, so there is no one true solution. The pull-up value may depend on what clock rate you need to communicate, like do you want fastest possible bus speed at the expense of using more current, or is slower enough so you can conserve current. The actual values also depend on bus capacitance, which likely you cannot even estimate now, because it depends on how long bus segments are on PCBs or cables, and how the wires are routed on PCB or what kind of cable is used and in which way you used the cable wires. It will also depend on the sensor drive strength which I could not immediately see from the data sheet. It also depends if you anyway want to use the TCA9548 mux and enable both sensors at the same time on two different bus segments.

So that's why there is usually no generic pull-up resistor values given, because they would likely be wrong for any specific case anyway.

So there is just a range between min/max values you can use, and you can calculate the min and max values based on what you have on the bus and need to be within bus specification and the speed you want to communicate at.

This is why you as the designer must gather information about the system, from all the chips and bus links between them.
For example, a common requirement is that when a chip pulls low and sinks current, it must be able to pull the voltage low enough for everyone on bus, and the amount of current it can sink will determine the lower resistance limit.

But in your case, the system gets pretty complex, if you have a 5V bus segment, and maybe just one or possibly two 3.3V bus segments enabled at a time. All current and voltage limits still apply, and signal rise/fall times, even if there are multiple pull-up resistors to different voltages.

If your sensor is capable of 3mA I2C bus, then you might start by allocating 1mA for all three pull-ups.
Or 2.5mA for the 5V bus and something like 0.1mA for each of the 3.3V buses. But then you also need to make sure the resistos are strong enough so when the bus is not used, the bus does not have glitches due to electrically noisy environment. It is all a balance of in which kind of environment you want the bus to work. And it's a tradeoff between everything.